# Fleet: Invalid Gradle JDK configuration found

Tags: java, gradle, jetbrains-ide, jetbrains-fleet

When I'm using JetBrains Fleet and open the Java project Gradle configuration file `build.gradle` it shows an error:

> Invalid Gradle JDK configuration found. `<a href='#open_external_system_settings'>Open Gradle Settings</a>`

```
com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.execution.ExternalSystemJdkException: Invalid Gradle JDK configuration found. <a href='#open_external_system_settings'>Open Gradle Settings</a> 
    
        at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.execution.LocalGradleExecutionAware.jdkConfigurationException(LocalGradleExecutionAware.kt:184)
        at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.execution.LocalGradleExecutionAware.prepareJvmForExecution(LocalGradleExecutionAware.kt:122)
        at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.execution.LocalGradleExecutionAware.prepareExecution(LocalGradleExecutionAware.kt:62)
        at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.internal.ExternalSystemResolveProjectTask.doExecute(ExternalSystemResolveProjectTask.java:90)
        at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.internal.AbstractExternalSystemTask.execute(AbstractExternalSystemTask.java:151)
        at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.internal.AbstractExternalSystemTask.execute(AbstractExternalSystemTask.java:135)
        at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.util.ExternalSystemUtil$2.executeImpl(ExternalSystemUtil.java:496)
        at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.util.ExternalSystemUtil$2.lambda$execute$0(ExternalSystemUtil.java:327)
        at com.intellij.openapi.project.DumbServiceHeavyActivities.suspendIndexingAndRun(DumbServiceHeavyActivities.java:21)
        at com.intellij.openapi.project.DumbServiceImpl.suspendIndexingAndRun(DumbServiceImpl.java:186)
        at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.util.ExternalSystemUtil$2.execute(ExternalSystemUtil.java:327)
        at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.util.ExternalSystemUtil$4.run(ExternalSystemUtil.java:619)
        at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.startTask(CoreProgressManager.java:424)
        at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl.startTask(ProgressManagerImpl.java:114)
        at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.lambda$runProcessWithProgressAsynchronously$6(CoreProgressManager.java:475)
        at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressRunner.lambda$submit$3(ProgressRunner.java:252)
        at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.lambda$runProcess$2(CoreProgressManager.java:188)
        at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.lambda$executeProcessUnderProgress$13(CoreProgressManager.java:590)
        at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.registerIndicatorAndRun(CoreProgressManager.java:665)
        at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.computeUnderProgress(CoreProgressManager.java:621)
        at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.executeProcessUnderProgress(CoreProgressManager.java:589)
        at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl.executeProcessUnderProgress(ProgressManagerImpl.java:60)
        at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.runProcess(CoreProgressManager.java:175)
        at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressRunner.lambda$submit$4(ProgressRunner.java:252)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$AsyncSupply.run(CompletableFuture.java:1768)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1136)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$PrivilegedThreadFactory$1$1.run(Executors.java:702)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$PrivilegedThreadFactory$1$1.run(Executors.java:699)
        at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:399)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$PrivilegedThreadFactory$1.run(Executors.java:699)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
```

How to configure Gradle JDK in JetBrains Fleet?

Comment: To me, it looks like there may be an issue with the JDK version that is set in your JAVA_HOME setting/environment variables. You may wish to check there and/or configure the Fleet JDK settings for your project.

Answer (score 1):

By default, Fleet uses the JDK from your `JAVA_HOME` environment variable. Before proceeding, make sure it is configured in your environment. Otherwise, you can [configure a custom JDK for your project](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/fleet/getting-started-with-java-in-fleet.html#configure-jdk) as shown in the documentation.

Also, the "java.home" property in `.fleet/settings.json` [user settings file](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/fleet/settings.html#user-settings) should help.

Please see a [documentation](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/fleet/getting-started-with-java-in-fleet.html#7115876c) for more details.